# Django - Selecting an specific row and col from a 2D List

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display a Vigenere Square in Django but I want to to specify a color to a specific row and column so that it can be identified from the rest of the square. With this implementation the whole square is colored. I'm looking to get the first row colored and the first column also colored. The rest must be white.

Template:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
            <table id="show-table">
              <tbody>
                {% for row in vigenereExample %}
                  {% if row.0 %}
                    <tr style="background-color: #98AFC7;">
                      {% for col in row %}
                          <td>
                            {{col}}
                          </td>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                  {% else %}
                    <tr>
                      {% for col in row %}
                        <td>
                          {{col}}
                        </td>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

View.py

```
def vigenereHome(request):
object = VigenereCipher()
vigenereSquare = object.getSquaredAlphabet()
vigenereExample = object.geSquareExample()
context = {
            'vigenereSquare' : vigenereSquare,
            'vigenereExample' : vigenereExample
}
return render(request, "VigenereCipher.html", context)
```

This is the class that builds the Square
VigenereCipher.py

```
class VigenereCipher:

squareAlphabet = []
squareExample = []

exampleKey = "NETWORK"
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
nonCapLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def __init__(self):
    # Initialize a list of lists. 27x27 array because of the Grid
    self.squaredAlphabet=[ [ '' for x in range(27)] for j in range(27)]
    self.squareExample=[['' for x in range(26)] for j in range(len(self.exampleKey) + 1)]

    # Create Grid on column
    for y in range(len(self.letters)):
        #self.squaredAlphabet[0][y+1] = "x"
        self.squaredAlphabet[0][y+1] = self.nonCapLetters[y]
        self.squareExample[0][y] = self.letters[y]

    # Create Grid on row
    for y in range(len(self.letters)):
        #self.squaredAlphabet[y+1][0] = "y"
        self.squaredAlphabet[y+1][0] = self.nonCapLetters[y]

    for y in range(len(self.exampleKey)):
        self.squareExample[y+1][0] = self.exampleKey[y]

    # Fill Vigenere Square
    for x in range(len(self.letters)):
        j = 0
        for y in range(len(self.letters)):
            j = y + x
            if(j > 25):
                j = j - 26
            self.squaredAlphabet[x+1][y+1] = self.letters[j]

    # For debugging purposes, display the Square.
    # for x in range(len(self.squaredAlphabet)):
    #     for y in range(len(self.squaredAlphabet)):
    #         print("Position: x", x, "y",  y, "=",  self.squaredAlphabet[x][y])

    # Fills the exampleSquare
    for x in range(len(self.exampleKey)):
        j = 0
        for y in range(len(self.letters)):
            j = self.letters.index(self.exampleKey[x]) + y
            if(j > 25):
                j = j - 26
            self.squareExample[x+1][y] = self.letters[j]
    print(self.squareExample)

def getSquaredAlphabet(self):
    return self.squaredAlphabet

def geSquareExample(self):
    return self.squareExample
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you need is

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <table id="show-table">
        <tbody>
            {% for row in vigenereExample %}
            <tr>
                {% for col in row %}
                    {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 or forloop.parentloop.counter0 == 0 %}
                    <td style="background-color: #98AFC7;">
                    {% else %}
                    <td>
                    {% endif %}
                        {{col}}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I know comments are not suppose to thank someone but thank you so much for this. I didn't know about the forloop.counter0 and forloop.parentloop.counter0. This simplifies so many things!